# Relative position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

An element with `position: relative;` is positioned relative to its normal position.

Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.

Here is the source: [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Now,how can I make relative position to work as viewport and adjust accordingly by setting height,width etc like fixed position.
It is possible in css or not?
If not then how can I do?

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLLx6yLa/)

Comment: Please add a fiddle for your code. It greatly helps the people trying to help you.

Comment: Ok,wait i'm adding fiddle

Comment: Oh @CodeRomeos please help now.

Comment: use `position: absolute;`

Comment: Why have you put the left:80px; in css? If you remove that 80px it will automatically adjust to viewport.

Comment: @Abhitalks, suppose there are ten different queires fetched and if absolute used,it will concide over each other,for that using relative but going against viewport.

Comment: @CodeRomeos it is my requirement to make TOP: 450px; LEFT: 651px for viewing but just posted a example,so i can't remove it.

Comment: You may use float for adjusting the columns to left and right.

Comment: How my friend to do this?

Comment: Ok,thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
div{
POSITION: relative; 
TOP: 450px; LEFT: 651px; 
width: calc(100% - 651px);
float: left;
}
```

You can also use javascript or jquery to do it.